# MUI DataGrid disable the complete row

Tags: typescript, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I have the columns

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params: GridValueGetterParams) =>
      `${params.row.firstName || ""} ${params.row.lastName || ""}`,
  },
];
```

data in rows

```
const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 14 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 31 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 31 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 11 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: 25 },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 },
];
```

I have my onRowClick funtionaly over there, like if we click on any row I'll take that row data for further operation.

**I just wanted row to be disable if age > 30**

(like shown in the image: [link](https://ibb.co/wYT0MTZ)

providing a link for code: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/currying-architecture-k679q3?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A70%2C31)

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You just need to read the exact param to handle the behavior. You can modify your onRowClick into like below.

```
onRowClick={(params: GridRowParams) => {
  if (params.row.age > 30) {
    console.log("Greater than 30. Selected age is", params.row.age);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Lower than 30. Selected age is", params.row.age);
}}
```

Full code modified by me: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/recursing-benji-nsf6qx?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00072a67fl0i8dz1%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00032a67x7ddvc4l%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00042a67ywatjgcl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00062a67sv60x0s1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls8lcu3j00032a67x7ddvc4l%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00022a67pxv2r20f%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A71%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A35%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A71%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A35%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FDemo.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00032a67x7ddvc4l%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00022a67pxv2r20f%2522%257D%252C%2522cls8lcu3j00062a67sv60x0s1%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00052a67n3u9kq2g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00062a67sv60x0s1%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00052a67n3u9kq2g%2522%257D%252C%2522cls8lcu3j00042a67ywatjgcl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls8lcu3j00042a67ywatjgcl%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)